# Is the following IP address and Subnet configuration valid for an internet host?

Tags: subnet, ip-address

IP: 218.50.10.5
Subnet: 255.255.255.240

Can you tell me how to calculate it?

Edit:

[image]

I have entered Yes to all of these but I believe I am wrong on the last one but I can't figure out how I am wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here. Fortunately, we have a [question with answers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) that explain IPv4 addressing and subnetting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have modified your question, I re-wrote my answer:

> Using the rules we learned in class ...

The rules for IPv4 address assignments massively changed in 1993. As far as I know there was smaller change after 2012. However many universities still teach the old rules (before 1993).

So it is difficult to answer your question not knowing what your university is teaching.

In the "real" internet of the year 2018, the answer is "yes" for all the entries in the list.

Comment: I guess I didn't ask my question properly. The question is "determine if these IP address configurations are valid for an Internet host" Then it gives me the IP and Subnet Mask I listed in my question. So I need to determine that the IP I am given does lie inside the available range given the Subnet Mask I have. Hope that clarifies?

Comment: I'll take it. I calculated them all out and it looked like they were all good and you say that is correct thank you good sir.